# How to add raw html to a success message in a Wordpress form

Tags: wordpress, forms, href

I have a fields that just contain text. Sadly it does not allow me to add html.
Is there any way to force this ?

The best way to explain this problem is with a picture.

[image]

If anyone has any idea let me know.
I'm new to wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert normal text box to wp editor

```
    //custom field
    $custom_shot_content_timer = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_shot_content_timer', true ); 


    //wp text editor
    $settings = array( 'textarea_name' => 'custom_shot_content_timer' );

    $editor_id = 'custom_shot_content_timer';

    $content = $custom_shot_content_timer;

    wp_editor( $content, $editor_id, $settings );
    //wp text editor
```

Screenshot
https://prnt.sc/22l8s9n
https://prnt.sc/22l8trb